# How can I get all of the files in C: drive with Directory.GetFiles?

Tags: vb.net

So, I have been trying to get all of the C: drive files with Directory.GetFiles, but I had no success. And yes, i'm a starter at VB.NET. Anybody know how to get all of the files from C: drive? (I'm only finding .exe files here)

Comment: You can't do it with a single call to `GetFiles` because you will encounter at least one inaccessible folder and it will fail. You need to write your own recursive file search. If you search the web for those keywords you'll find plenty of examples.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its quite an in-depth project to accomplish, however, it is not too difficult once you get your head around the fundamentals. So definitely go for it!

Start off with directories - see [Get directories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ff71z1w(v=vs.110).aspx)

The Files - see [Get files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx)

Rather than scanning the whole of your C: drive, start off with creating a folder and putting some folders and files in there to test with.

You can use the **SearchPattern** to search `*.exe` for your current requirement, or `t*.d` would return "Test.docx" as well as "template.dll" (if they are in the folder you are searching

Use ListBox if you are familiar with them to show results. Keep googling! - There's lots of articles out there, the more you code.. and get wrong.. - The better you'll become!